# ArcGis : Esri Map " Invalid Token Used To Access a secure service "

Tags: android, arcgis, esri

I'm new to arcgis and esri maps ,I'm trying to make route between two points ,
Here is my Code :

```
map.setOnLongPressListener(new OnLongPressListener() {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public boolean onLongPress(final float x, final float y) {

            grahpicslayer.removeAll();

            final Point loc = map.toMapPoint(x, y);


            grahpicslayer.addGraphic(new Graphic(loc, new SimpleMarkerSymbol(Color.RED, 20, SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE.CIRCLE)));

            //Display the red color diamond graphics
            map.addLayer(grahpicslayer);

            //zoom the map to the location
            map.zoomToResolution(loc, 20.0);


            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {


                    // new code
                    try {

                        String CLIENT_SECRET = "";
                        String CLIENT_ID = "";


                        //Prepare user credentials
                        UserCredentials userCredentials = new UserCredentials();
                        userCredentials.setAuthenticationType(UserCredentials.AuthenticationType.TOKEN);
                        userCredentials.setSSLRequired(false);
                        userCredentials.setUserToken(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);



            /*initialize RouteTask*/
                        String routeTaskURL = "https://route.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/Route/NAServer/Route_World";
                        RouteTask rt = RouteTask.createOnlineRouteTask(routeTaskURL, userCredentials);
                        RouteParameters rp = rt.retrieveDefaultRouteTaskParameters();
                        NAFeaturesAsFeature rfaf = new NAFeaturesAsFeature();

                        // Convert point to EGS (decimal degrees)
                        Point p = (Point) GeometryEngine.project(loc, wm,
                                egs);

                        //mlocation is your latitude and longitude point provided by GPS location in decimal degrees
                        StopGraphic point1 = new StopGraphic(mLocation);
                        StopGraphic point2 = new StopGraphic(p);

                        String message = "point 1 == " + ((point1 == null) ? "null" : point1.getName()) + "point 2 == " + ((point2 == null) ? "null" : point2.getName());

                        Message msg = Message.obtain(); // Creates an new Message instance
                        msg.obj = message; // Put the string into Message, into "obj" field.
                        msg.setTarget(h); // Set the Handler
                        msg.sendToTarget(); //Send the message


                        rfaf.setFeatures(new Graphic[]{point1, point2});

                        rfaf.setCompressedRequest(true);
                        rp.setStops(rfaf);
                        rp.setOutSpatialReference(wm);

                        RouteResult mresults = rt.solve(rp);

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        String message = "ex : " + e.toString();

                        Message msg = Message.obtain(); // Creates an new Message instance
                        msg.obj = message; // Put the string into Message, into "obj" field.
                        msg.setTarget(h); // Set the Handler
                        msg.sendToTarget(); //Send the message
                    }
                }
            }).start();
            return true;
        }

    });
```

The code for getting current location based on location change listener

```
/**
     * If location changes, update our current location. If being found for
     * the first time, zoom to our current position with a resolution of 20
     */
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        if (loc == null)
            return;
        boolean zoomToMe = (mLocation == null) ? true : false;
        mLocation = new Point(loc.getLongitude(), loc.getLatitude());
        if (zoomToMe) {
            Point p = (Point) GeometryEngine.project(mLocation, egs, wm);
            map.zoomToResolution(p, 20.0);
        }
    }
```

After running this code i face this error :

> com.esri.core.io.EsriSecurityException : Invalid Token Used To Access a secure service - https://route.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/Route/NAServer/Route_World

Comment: As the error says, probably you'r using an invalid token.

Comment: how to create a valid token and use it

Comment: Read "Requesting Tokens" section : http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java/index.htm#token_service.htm

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set a token value in your code but no value is being assigned, also the name of the variables (CLIENT_SECRET and CLIENT_ID) implies an app login using OAuth2.

You have 3 options for accessing the routing service, a user OAuth2 login, an app OAuth2 login or a token based user login. The preferred method is a user OAuth2 login so that the user who is logging in will use their ArcGIS Online named user account and any credits that are required will come from their subscription. There is a [code sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/sample-code/oauth2/) for a user base OAuth2 login on the developer portal.

If you still want to use a token based login then you need to set the username and password for the UserCredential so that a token can be generated or use the method you are already calling but pass in a valid token string.

I would recommend reading the [authentication documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/authentication/accessing-arcgis-online-services/) on the developer portal if you haven't already as it gives a comprehensive description of each option.

Comment: Dear Dave, I left the ( CLIENT_SECRET and CLIENT_ID )   empty cause i think it shouldn't be shared " if you want me to share it with you i can do it ". About OAUth2 i think it's not logic for making the user login to arcgis to use the route the user should be able to use this service without login, Am i right ? , if right what should i do .

Comment: No, that service requires a named user in order to access it as it is a premium service, you can see the access information at http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/#/Accessing_services/02r3000000nm000000/. So back to your example, the CLIENT_SECRET and CLIENT_ID indicates an app login but you are calling setToken which implies you have a token, but you don't so you need to make sure you pick one of the 3 authentication methods I mentioned above.

Comment: So , what i can do if i want to make route in the app without require the user to login as normal routing map

Comment: You can use any of the 3 authentication methods but they would each require some form of hard coding. The one that makes the most sense if you don't want the users' to login themselves is the application login so using your CLIENT_ID and SECRET but you don't set the token to those values, you need to generate it using the OAuth2 endpoint and then use the access token that is returned when calling the routing service. See https://developers.arcgis.com/authentication/mobile-and-native-user-logins/ for more information. Also, be aware that this will consume credits from your developer account.

Comment: Do you mean that the route service is a paid service